# Annotation specs - AutoML (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

I'm using the Natural Language module on Google Cloud Platform and more specifically AUTOML for text classification.
I come across this error which I do not understand when I have finished importing my data and the text has been processed :

Error: The dataset has too many annotation specs, the maximum allowed number is 5000.

What does it mean? Have you already got it?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [Google Quotas and Limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas). Next time, please do more research before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [AutoML Quotas & Limits](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/quotas) documentation for better understanding.

It seems that you are touching the highest limit of labels per dataset. Check it on the [AutoML limits](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/quotas#limits) --> Labels per dataset --> 2 - 5000 (for classification).

Take into account that limits, unlike quotas, cannot be increased.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error while I was certain that my number of labels are below 5000. It turns out to be an error with my CSV formatting.

When you create your text data using to_csv() in Pandas, it will only quotes that part of text data that contains comma, while AutoML Text wants you to quote all lines of the text. I have written the solution [in this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70285054/17447435)